# Bypass Ajax Autoscroll

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im building a social media analytics programme and im having a hard time with the scrolling ajax on soundcloud. the ajax requires you to scroll to the bottom to load more followers.

(for example https://soundcloud.com/secretlycanadian/followers )

I want to be able to load all these followers instantly, i can achieve this by simply using JS to scroll down, but the time it takes to do this on large accounts is unacceptable really.

Can anyone think of any other approaches to solving this that i could look into? Just kinda stuck on where to even start looking on this one.

Thanks guys
+ Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just remove the limit parameter from the URL?

Example URL (limited to 60 followers):
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/11415557/followers?client_id=XXXXXXX&limit=60&linked_partitioning=1&offset=60

Limit set to 200:
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/11415557/followers?client_id=XXXXXXX&limit=200&linked_partitioning=1&offset=00

You will however need a valid client_id. I can't tell if there's any server-side limit.

Comment: Thanks, thats one possibility to look into. However would rather avoid the API if possible because of limits.